c++11 std::map with lot of elements doesn't work. Furthermore I need to use upper_bound function but insert function stucks
Ok guys I need your help.. I'm fighting with a std::map in c++11 because I need to store more than two outputs during a for loop. To be more clear I should work with something like this:

std::map<std::pair<int, std::pair<long long int, long int>>, std::pair<std::pair<long long int, int>, std::pair<std::string, long int>>> loopMap;

I think the map himself is not wrong because VSCode is not giving me errors, but it's not working as expected.
I don't care about the map order, but what I need is to use loopMap.upper_bound(long int) to grab my desired value from the last long int in the map. Originally I placed this long int at the map begin but values inserted during the for loop can be duplicated, so to not miss outputs I had to move it at the end of the map and insert at the begin a simple int that works as a counter.
I'm editing the map to find the right way to make it work but if loopMap.upper_bound(long int) works, loopMap.insert() stucks and considering the map complexity it's not easy to be filled with operators[].
Thanks for your help guys.
My code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
   std::map<std::pair<int, std::pair<long long int, long int>>, 
   std::pair<std::pair<long long int, int>, std::pair<std::string, 
   long int>>> loopMap;

   loopMap.insert(std::make_pair(10, std::make_pair(123456789LL, 
   987654321L)), std::make_pair(std::make_pair(123456789LL, 42), 
   std::make_pair("example", 987654321L)));

   if (loopMap.size() > 0)
   {
      auto res = loopMap.upper_bound(2); // I do not know the LL & L int values. So how I can use this?
      std::cout << "The lowest \"int\" is: " << (*res).first << 
      " and its final \"long int\" is:" << (*res).second.second.second << 
      std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}

An example of what I want:
$ The lowest "int" is: 10 and its final "long int" is: 987654321
Compiler gives this error for .insert():

no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert

and the same for the .upper_bound():

no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::upper_bound


"I need to store more than two outputs during a for loop" - I think a [mre] would help me to see what it is you are trying to do.

"values inserted during the for loop can be duplicated" - that implies you don't want a map at all.  Why aren't you just using a std::vector?

Besides a MRE, This would be clearer to me if you defined key and value classes / structs, and explained why each needs nesting instead of being a flat list of elements.  Also remember the key is unique so keys of (1, 8242) and (5, 8242) are 2 separate map keys they are not somehow merged together into a new (6, 8242) key.

@ChrisDodd I need all outputs including duplicates, because only value can be duplicated but not the rest of the map elements. Probably I have to consider a std::multimap...

@DaveS do you mean to store outputs into an array or what you mean with flat list? And no.. I wont merge outputs...

@TedLyngmo I hope it's enough as example. consider it as a code extraction because the full code is obviously more complex, but the sense is that I need the lowest int at the begin and the last long int at the end.

@CikoXp With the updated question: Are you wondering why it doesn't compile? (none of the four most used compilers accepts it) - If that's not it, take the time to make a [mre] so that we can observe the same problem you observe. Also, please fill in the blanks: "An example of what I want:" - but it's a program. No output. What do you expect the program to produce?

@TedLyngmo check my edited question. Now it's more clear. Also I added the compiler errors.

@CikoXp It still does not compile, so, is that what you wonder about? (none of the four most used compilers in the world accepts it - in pedantic mode)

For your extended example, just use txtMap.begin() rather than upper_bound.  You also need another make_pair wrapped around the argument in insert, which takes a single argument (a key,value pair)

@TedLyngmo compiler fails because I have not a solution. I'm here for this....

@CikoXp But that means that you are asking about syntax instead of what it is your title says. You have a lot of text in your question describing what you want to do, but the question is really about how to populate a map? Correct?

Say you insert two keys, {10, {2, 3}} and {10, {1, 4}}. Then call upper_bound(2). Which element do you want to look up? (a) the second because 1 < 2; (b) the first because 3 < 4; (c) the first because it was inserted earlier chronologically; (d) either one, doesn't matter; (e) some other criterion.

In your example, what's txMap and how, if at all, is it related to loopMap?

@ChrisDodd so I should make pairs before make_pair? In this way?
std::pair<int, std::pair<long long int, long int>> mykey = std::make_pair(1, std::make_pair(123456789LL, 987654321L)); and pass directly the mykey to the make_pair?

@CikoXp What's needed to be able to answer your question is that we known what you need help with. You've presented code that does not compile. Is that where you are stuck? You seem to avoid that fact and pretend that the code actually compiles and does the wrong thing. Focus please.

@IgorTandetnik txMap and loopMap are simply two versions of the same map... anyway I fixed the code above. Furthermore as I said I do not know the rest of the values so I don't know how to use upper_bound().

@TedLyngmo exactly. I need a way to properly compile...

@CikoXp Your code won't compile even with the first insert into the map. Wouldn't that be a good place to start? upper_bound comes later - much later.

I'm not asking how to use upper_bound. I'm asking what the end result of that use should be. Imagine there's a magical loopMap.do_what_I_mean(2) function - what result, specifically, would you like this magic function to produce? You never explained with any specificity what it is you are trying to achieve. You chose a pretty bizarre data structure that, on the surface, doesn't make much sense. But perhaps it's in fact a perfect fit for your problem = no way to tell since you didn't explain the problem it's meant to be a fit for.

@IgorTandetnik in my question:
what I want:
$ The lowest "int" is: 10 and its final "long int" is: 987654321

@CikoXp But "your code" isn't real code until it compiles unfortunately. It's hard to overlook things that makes it hard to answer your question. Please make it compile first  -  or not, but then, ask about compilation errors.

What does "final" mean here? Can there be two entries that both start with 10? If so, which of them is "final"? Anyway, the "lowest int" in a std::map is always at loopMap.begin(), so not clear why you are trying to use upper_bound. And also, you don't need to store all elements just to find the smallest one; so maybe you don't need a container at all. Again, it comes back to what the ultimate goal of the exercise is.

@IgorTandetnik I do not want the 1st entry in the map.. I know map.begin() what do. I want ask to the map the 1st double higher than my desired value that can change every time. Check my solution. thanks anyway.

printf("The lowest \"int\" is: 10 and its final \"long int\" is: 987654321\n"); is a short program that satisfies your described success criteria.  A large part of programming is being able to actually describe your problem.

SOLVED!
The solution was move my map from std::map to std::multimap to allow duplicated outputs from for loop. Furthermore, to work with keys I have properly modified the map structure moving all unknown elements in the value field. In this way I can use upper_bound() simply with my desired long int value.
I hope it's at least half as clear to you as it is to me.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

bool MapLoop()
{
    std::multimap<double, std::pair<std::string, std::pair<long long int, std::pair<int, std::pair<long long int, long int>>>>> txMap;

    double key1 = 0.00842342;
    std::string str = "first_example";
    long long int lli1 = 123456789LL;
    int someInt = 42;
    long long int lli2 = 987654321LL;
    long int li2 = 876543210L;
    double key2 = 0.01000000;

    txMap.insert(std::make_pair(key1, std::make_pair(str, std::make_pair(lli1, std::make_pair(someInt, std::make_pair(lli2, li2))))));
    txMap.insert(std::make_pair(key1, std::make_pair("second_example", std::make_pair(lli1 + 1, std::make_pair(someInt + 1, std::make_pair(lli2 + 1, li2 + 1))))));
    txMap.insert(std::make_pair(key2, std::make_pair("third_example", std::make_pair(lli1 + 2, std::make_pair(someInt + 2, std::make_pair(lli2 + 2, li2 + 2))))));

    std::cout << "txMap size: " << txMap.size() << std::endl;

    for (const auto& it : txMap)
    {
        std::cout << "\"" << it.first << " : " << it.second.first << " => " << it.second.second.first << " : " << it.second.second.second.first << " => " << it.second.second.second.second.first << " : " << it.second.second.second.second.second << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
    
    if (!txMap.empty())
    {
        auto res = txMap.upper_bound(0.00999999);
        std::cout << "The lowest \"double\" is: " << res->first << " and its \"long int\" is: " << res->second.second.second.second.second << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    if (!MapLoop())
        std::cout << "MapLoop() do not works!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Her's my desired result:
txMap size: 3
"0.00842342 : first_example => 123456789 : 42 => 987654321 : 876543210"
"0.00842342 : second_example => 123456790 : 43 => 987654322 : 876543211"
"0.01 : third_example => 123456791 : 44 => 987654323 : 876543212"
The lowest "double" is: 0.01 and its "long int" is: 876543212

exactly what I was looking for... thanks to all anyway!

What I was asking earlier was why not define something like struct MapValue { string s; long long llv1; int iv1; long long llv2; ... } instead of all the nesting of nesting of nesting?  map accepts class/struct as the value.

@DaveS : because I'm working on a temp file to write a dedicated function. In the main code instead, map will strore  only struct. ;-)
